# Linuxbrew doesn't see the latest version of node.js

Tags: node.js, linuxbrew

I'm trying to install `node.js` on Ubuntu using `linuxbrew`. I'm running the following commands:

```
brew update
brew info node
```

the output is

```
node: stable 6.0.0, HEAD
```

However version 6.1.0 should already be available (you could verify it in e.g [braumeister](http://braumeister.org/formula/node))

Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linuxbrew is built on top of Homebrew and updates to the latter need to be manually ported to the former, which is why you can expect a small update lag. Braumeister and similar websites get their infos from Homebrew.